# How to get an app running on Heroku with Python Django on MySql? KeyError: '', code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: python, mysql, django, settings, keyerror

I have been trying to get my first application on the web.
Using as cloud application platform [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).
The app is built in Python with Django and is meant to use a MYSQL database for which is provided as add_on JAWSDB. The url of the JAWSDB is set to the DATABASE_URL. My app code is public on [GitHub](https://github.com/bartelba/LearningNow) . I am able to deploy the code on Heroku but get an application error when I open the app.
(See log below).
I think it has to do with [my_settings](https://github.com/bartelba/LearningNow/blob/master/learningnow/my_settings.py), honestly I don't know what is to be corrected.

1. Is it the database that get not opened? `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=learningnow.herokuapp.com`However it is possible to connect to the remote database via MySql workbench.
2. The log is referring to

> engine = SCHEMES[url.scheme] if engine is None else engine KeyError:
>   ''

Are the

> django_heroku.settings(locals())

for which I assume the DATABASE_URL is found, but it seems not working.

3. Has it to do with the config = parse(s, engine, conn_max_age, **ssl_require**). However in my last attempt i have put

   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
                   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                   'NAME': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ[DATABASE_URL],
                   ssl_require=False),
       }

2019-03-02T15:33:06.132322+00:00 app[web.1]: engine = SCHEMES[url.scheme] if engine is None else engine
2019-03-02T15:33:06.132370+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: ''
2019-03-02T15:33:07.351885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=learningnow.herokuapp.com request_id=28373f9d-99b1-4362-8054-de2e72aac130 fwd="81.207.96.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-02T15:33:08.147290+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=learningnow.herokuapp.com request_id=073e5f94-a1ce-41ea-979c-4dabb341ea86 fwd="81.207.96.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

See the last part of my_settings.py file which is meant to connect and open the app on Heroku:

```
# Heroku settings
```

if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'NAME': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ[DATABASE_URL],
                ssl_require=False),
    }
}

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure().
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers.
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static asset configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Any suggestions on how to get this better?

Comment: Please read on how to ask a proper question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. , as your question is too broad and nobody would have so much time and effort to read such a long question. Please summarise your problem briefly so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, several code changes needed to happen.
See [enter link description here](https://github.com/bartelba/LearningNow)

for a full working application for Heroku, connected to a JawsDB add-on (MySql) database using the framework of Python with Django.

Esspecially the connection to the JawsDb had to be set: See last part of the my_settings.txt file:

```
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
import django_heroku

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['learningnow.herokuapp.com']

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

database_attr = DATABASE_URL.split(':')

JaName = database_attr[3].split('/')[1].rstrip("'")
JaUser = database_attr[1].lstrip('//')
JaPwrd = database_attr[2].split('@')[0]
JaHost = database_attr[2].split('@')[1]
JaPort = int(database_attr[3].split('/')[0])

DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': JaName,
        'USER': JaUser,
        'PASSWORD': JaPwrd,
        'HOST': JaHost,
    }
}`
```